# RaisedButton rendered with a semi-transparent gray fill in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a RaisedButton inside a Column, which is inside a Stack

```
Stack(
   children: [
       PageView(
         children: [...],
       ),
       Column(
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, 
         children: [
           RaisedButton(
             color: Colors.teal,
             child: Text("Button"),
           ),
           ...
           ),
         ...
```

However, instead of the button being rendered with a teal fill, it is gray and semi-transparent.
[Here it is on top of an orange Container.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m16oo.png)

Is there any way for me to force this button to be teal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If **onPressed** is not provided for RaisedButton it will show up as garyed or disabled.

You can set the color to be shown for disabled RaisedButton by providing value for **disabledColor**

For more details visit this [link](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html)